# Change the column name of only first occurance in excel vba

Tags: vba, excel

My dataset have manys columns with column names similar to

ABC AAA SSD AAA VFD FDS AAA

We have many columns with same name. Here it is AAA.

I want to rename first AAA into "FIRST" and other AAAs as "OTHERS". Since first AAA can appear in any column number, we can't use the column reference("A","B") to refer it.

Only if there is no-other-way, we can refer the column_reference.

If I used IF statement, it will change all statements. So what can we do?

I want this to be done in Excel VBA because I have to apply same sort of methods to similar workbooks. My program is almost over for a project and I got struck in this. Please help me.

Comment: Maybe post what you have so far so we can help you from there.. we do not have the complete context so it's very hard to answer

Comment: Okay. I will edit. I called the whole worksheet
if cell.value="I am" then cell.value="Gender"; 

The problem is "employment" column's name is also "I am". So it also got changed into "Gender"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I understand you want to change just 1 column so if that is correct then just do this

```
Dim hasChanged As Boolean

'and now do your code with a small change
hasChanged = False
If cell.Value = "I am" And hasChanged = False Then
    cell.Value = "Gender"
    hasChanged = True
End If
```